# How to extract supplementary info if certain link reside in the div

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I would like to extract an `url` together with supplementary information from each `div`

Currently, Im able to extract all the `download` url as:

```
for link in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    if 'https://figshare.com/ndownloader/files' in link['href']:
        print(link['href'])
```

But, I also would like to extract the infromation reside in `class="_2qbpz"`. For example, in the `html` below, the information within the `class="_2qbpz"` is `s01_060926_1n.set.`

```html
<div class="_2bEHu"><button class="xaHFp" tabindex="-1" type="button"><span class="_2qbpz">s01_060926_1n.set.</span><span class="_2f04f">zip</span><span class="_3c2ks"> (233.62 MB)</span></button>
  <div class="ElLvs"><button aria-label="View file" tabindex="-1" class="_1Nt_k _1jrLT _2Cyxu" type="button"><svg aria-hidden="true" fill="transparent" height="36" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" width="20" class="_746D7" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 20 36" xmlns="https://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path clip-rule="evenodd" d="M20 17.965C20 18.89 16.713 24 10 24c-6.095 0-10-5.134-10-6.035C0 17.161 3.819 12 9.943 12 16.498 12 20 17.161 20 17.965zm-4.887.05c0-2.659-2.301-4.814-5.14-4.814-2.84 0-5.14 2.155-5.14 4.814 0 2.658 2.3 4.813 5.14 4.813 2.839 0 5.14-2.155 5.14-4.813zm-5.14-3.916c-2.31 0-4.183 1.753-4.183 3.916 0 2.163 1.873 3.917 4.183 3.917 2.31 0 4.182-1.753 4.182-3.917 0-2.163-1.873-3.916-4.182-3.916z" fill-rule="evenodd"></path></svg></button>
    <a
      aria-label="Download file" href="https://figshare.com/ndownloader/files/14249783" class="_2tVAZ"><svg aria-hidden="true" fill="transparent" height="36" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" width="16" class="_1VlIg" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 16 36" xmlns="https://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path clip-rule="evenodd" d="m9.807 18.891 1.698-1.66a.82.82 0 0 1 1.14 0l.855.836a.776.776 0 0 1 0 1.114L8.806 23.77a.82.82 0 0 1-1.14 0L2.972 19.18a.776.776 0 0 1 0-1.114l.855-.836a.82.82 0 0 1 1.14 0l1.697 1.659V11a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h1.143a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v7.891zM0 25.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h15a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v1a.5.5 0 0 1-.5.5H.5a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5v-1z" fill-rule="evenodd"></path></svg></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

May I know how to properly extract the said supplementary information?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://figshare.com/articles/dataset/Multi-channel_EEG_recordings_during_a_sustained-attention_driving_task_preprocessed_dataset_/7666055/3"
page = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

for link in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    if 'https://figshare.com/ndownloader/files' in link['href']:
        print(link['href'])
```

Comment: Try changing `html.parser` Some time it is unable to parse html5 pages and so does'nt extract complete info. You can use `html5-parser`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can directly call the API, play with `offset` and `limit`

```py
import requests

limit = 10

data = requests.post('https://figshare.com/api/graphql?thirdPartyCookies=true&type=current&operation=getPublicItemFiles',
             json = {"operationName":"getPublicItemFiles","variables":{"itemId":7666055,"version":3,"offset":20,"limit":limit},"query":"query getPublicItemFiles($itemId: Int!, $version: Int, $offset: Int!, $limit: Int!) {\n  publicItem: itemVersion(id: $itemId, version: $version) {\n    id\n    files(offset: $offset, limit: $limit) {\n      hasMore\n      items: elements {\n        id\n        name\n        status\n        extension\n        size\n        viewerType\n        mimeType\n        virusScanInfo {\n          virusFound\n        }\n        md5\n        isLinkOnly\n        thumb\n        previewMeta\n        suppliedMd5\n        previewState\n        previewLocation\n        downloadUrl\n      }\n    }\n  }\n}\n"}).json()

files = [[i['name'], i['downloadUrl']] for i in data['data']['publicItem']['files']['items']]
print(files)

# [['s13_060217m.set.zip', 'https://figshare.com/ndownloader/files/14249882'],
#  ['s14_060319m.set.zip', 'https://figshare.com/ndownloader/files/14249885'],
#  ['s14_060319n.set.zip', 'https://figshare.com/ndownloader/files/14249888'],
#  ['s22_080513m.set.zip', 'https://figshare.com/ndownloader/files/14249891'],
#  ['s22_090825n.set.zip', 'https://figshare.com/ndownloader/files/14249894'],
#  ['s22_090922m.set.zip', 'https://figshare.com/ndownloader/files/14249900'],
#  ['s22_091006m.set.zip', 'https://figshare.com/ndownloader/files/14249903'],
#  ['s23_060711_1m.set.zip', 'https://figshare.com/ndownloader/files/14249906'],
#  ['s31_061020m.set.zip', 'https://figshare.com/ndownloader/files/14249909'],
#  ['s31_061103n.set.zip', 'https://figshare.com/ndownloader/files/14249912']]
```

Comment: This is compact. Out of curiosity, do we have to manually assign the text especially under to json?

Comment: yes, you need to play with offset and limit. The JSON has `itemId` which comes from your requested URL `...reprocessed_dataset_/<<<7666055>>>/3...`. If you need first 10 elements then offset=0 limit=10, then if you need next 10 then offset=10 limit=10 likewise

Comment: Say I want to implement this on different website, do I need to manually change these, say> `query":"query getPublicItemFiles($itemId: Int!, $version: Int, $offset: Int!, $limit: Int!) "
                             "{\n  publicItem: itemVersion(id: $itemId, version: $version) "
                             "{\n    id\n    files(offset: $offset, limit: $limi`

Comment: If you are using chrome then right-click --> Inspect --> network --> refresh the page --> you cab see a POST request is happening at `https://figshare.com/api/graphql?thirdPartyCookies=true&type=current&operation=getPublicItemFiles`

Comment: I think you need to change the item id and the limit and offset like how much data you want. Just edit this part `"variables":{"itemId":7666055,"version":3,"offset":20,"limit":limit}`